# using input type color for changing the color of the text

Tags: html, input

Is possible a script like this:

When you change the color from input type=color it changes automatically the color of the text ?

 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("changetext");
var text = document.getElementById("text");

input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  text.style.color = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="changetext" type="color">
<p id="text">Text<p>
```

Or with JQuery

```
$('input[type="color"]').on('change', function() {
  $("p").css("color", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Without jquery isnt possible?